# SSL Certificate issues for everything

Tags: windows-10, certificate, ssl-certificate

I recently factory reset my Windows 10 computer. I can no longer access Internet on any app. I tried chrome, steam, ie. I get "invalid SSL certificate" or "ERR_PROXY_CERTIFICATE_INVALID". This seems to be a network issue as I am using school internet and I was able to access the internet normally from a mobile hotspot. Everything was fine before the reset. How can I get around this?

Comment: Check the date of your system. If there are certificate errors for every page and app usually this means that the system date is totally wrong (e.g. 4 years in the past or future).

Comment: If @Robert's suggestion doesn't work, please list the OS being utilized, as Windows and Linux deal with certificate stores differently.

Comment: @Robert Date is accurate

Comment: The error message indicates that you use a proxy. Are you sure the proxy works. Do you really need a proxy? If not remove the proxy settings from Windows Internet settings.

Comment: @Robert Windows settings indicate I am not using a proxy. Could it be a problem with the network?

Comment: You should edit your question and add more details. About the used network; was Internet working before? What was changed in the last time?

Comment: Is this a corporate network? /edit: Ah, a school network. Is this truly *your* computer? The proxy (transparent or explicit) you’re using is performing SSL interception.

Comment: @DanielB I own the computer. I am connected to the school network

Comment: Do you get the option to look at the certificate that is supposedly invalid? You may need to install a special root certificate supplied by your school's IT department. Bear in mind that this will allow them to log everything you do online, even on secure pages.

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the certificate details to a website like google.com, this will help us determine if the problem is with the ISP or a problem with your browser and/or OS.

Comment: Does the school require you to install some software or certificate (root) to use their network?

Comment: @Arjan I have never had to in the past